# PHP Instagram-API: Caption text does not exist

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, instagramapi-mgp25

I use [Instagram-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) for the posting images with captions. I try:

```
$ig->timeline->uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ["caption" => "Hello world!"]);
```

The request is completed, the image is successfully uploaded, but the caption is empty.

When I run the example [uploadPhoto.php](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/examples/uploadPhoto.php), the image is also loaded without a title.

How can I fix that?

Comment: The caption will also not appear if you use a lot of hashtags in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$photoFilename = Enter Path here;

$photo = new \InstagramAPI\Media\Photo\InstagramPhoto($photoFilename);

$captionText = 'Hello world!';

$ig->timeline->uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => $captionText]);
```

Run this Code it works Properly.

If Any Issue came then send me your code, I will correct it.